pipe generator : geometry nodes - impossible configuration
I would like to do what is in the image below.
applying the object to all the curves of the line automatically
The object has to follow the tangency of the curve.
This would be the result (image below) but in all the curves of the line automatically, since I have to do this in 50 lines at once.

Is there a way for this cylinder to follow the tangency of the curve without deforming only the ends?

Thanks

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Could you add to the question a picture of the object you would like to add ? Is it a mesh ? Or is it a curve ? Is the cross-section to be scaled ? How is modelled the junction with the pipes ?
